# Dataframe with fixed length (over writing)

Tags: python, dataframe

I write a code that generates a mass amount of data in each round. So, I need to only store data for the last 10 rounds. How can I create a dataframe which erases the oldest object when I add a need object (over-writing)? The order of observations -from old to new- should be maintained. Is there any simple function or data format to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: either .append() and .iloc[] or create the dataframe from a dict of object with 10 keys

Comment: This seems like a fixed-length queue, not a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```py
def ins(arr, item):
    if len(arr) < 10:
        arr.insert(0, item)
    else:
        arr.pop()
        arr.insert(0, item)

ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

ins(ex, 'a')
print(ex)
# ['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

ins(ex, 'b')
print(ex)
# ['b', 'a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In order for this to work you MUST pass a list as argument to the function `ins()`, so that the new item is inserted and the 10th is removed (if there is one).
(I considered that the question is not pandas specific, but rather a way to store a maximum amount of items in an array)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd prefer to work with DataFrame rather than a list because it is faster for large datasets. I remember that there was a simple function to do it in DataFrame. Anyhow, thanks :) @teodoro

Comment: I found a similar function for DataFrame https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html